# why does the java compiler choose to use char[]

Tags: java

java version:

java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

Test.java

```java
package com.test.cast;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static Map<String, Object> MAP = new HashMap<>(2);
    static {
        MAP.put("int", 1);
        MAP.put("string", "2");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // throws ClassCastException
        String.valueOf(get("int"));
    }

    public static <T> T get(String k) {
        Object o = MAP.get(k);
        T o1 = (T) o;
        return o1;
    }
}
```

the code throws ClassCastException

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [C
    at com.test.cast.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Test.class

```java
public class Test {
    public static Map<String, Object> MAP = new HashMap(2);

    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // why char[]
        String.valueOf((char[])get("int"));
    }

    public static <T> T get(String k) {
        Object o = MAP.get(k);
        return o;
    }

    static {
        MAP.put("int", 1);
        MAP.put("string", "2");
    }
}
```

why does the java compiler choose to use char[]

why not use String.valueOf(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the compiler prefers the overload that doesn't require a boxing/unboxing conversion to occur.

The overload resolution algorithm roughly goes like this (an adaptation of [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) in the spec):

- First find the applicable overloads without considering boxing and unboxing, or variable arity parameters (varargs).
- If nothing is found, find the applicable overloads considering boxing and unboxing, but not varargs.
- If still nothing is found, consider both boxing and unboxing, *and* varargs.

`char[]` was selected, because no unboxing from `T` was needed - `char[]` is a reference type, and so is `T`. `int`, on the other hand, is a primitive type. To select the `int` overload, `T` would need to be inferred as the reference type `Integer`, because type parameters cannot be primitive types. Then an *unboxing* conversion has to occur, to convert it to an `int`.

If there was only the `int` overload, it would have been selected.